# Trying to use angular-recorder: how to send result file to server?

Tags: blob

I'm using this https://github.com/logbon72/angular-recorder and eventually i'll get mp3 file. How i can sent this file to server by POST request ? 
Can i send the mp3 file to server or Blob only ?
i can not get result voice file.

Comment: How would you send _any_ binary information via a POST request? What is the question here?

Comment: i can not get result file.

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37908521/edit) the question to add details to it. This is not a forum. Result file from _what_?

Answer (score 0):

logbon72/angular-recorder is a Fork of sathyapulse/angular-recorder. There, some people comment similar issues. Then copy the reply I sent to one of them:

Just search "control.save" in angular-audio-recorder.js file ( near line 377 ) and write this:

```
control.save = function (fileName) {
    if (!service.isAvailable() || status.isRecording || !control.audioModel) {
      return false;
    }

    var formData = new FormData();
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var content = control.audioModel;
    var blob = new Blob([content], { type: "audio/mp3"});
    formData.append("file", blob);
    request.open("POST", "/app/api/upload/audioMessage.php", true);
    request.send(formData);
  };
```

Just in case, my uploader php file ( /app/api/upload/audioMessage.php ) is something like this:

```
<?php
$dest_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/storage/audio_messages/';
if(!file_exists($dest_dir)) mkdir($dest_dir, 0777);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $dest_dir . uniqid() . ".mp3");
```

Pay atention to set the audioModel attribute in your audioRecorder directive.